# Polymorphism between components in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have different classes (models) who are children of a parent. Every child has its own form, but I would like the Component who has the parent references renders the specific form depending the child. An example:

**Models**

```ts
export interface Item {
    title: string;
}

export class Exercise implements Item {
    constructor(public title:string, public description:string);
}

export class Break implements Item {
    constructor(public title:string, public time:number);
}
```

**Forms**

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'item-form',
    template: `<item></item>
    `,  
    inputs: ['model:item']
})
export abstract class ItemFormComponent {
    model: Item;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'item-form',
    template: `
        <form #exerciseForm="ngForm">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required
           [(ngModel)]="model.title"
           ngControl="title" #name="ngForm" >
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required
           [(ngModel)]="model.description"
           ngControl="desription" #name="ngForm" >
        </form>
    `,  
    providers: [ExerciseService],
    inputs: ['model:exercise']
})
export class ExerciseFormComponent extends ItemFormComponent {
    model = new Exercise("Title", "Description"); 

    constructor(private _exerciseService: ExerciseService) {
        super();
    }
}

@Component({                                                                                          
    selector: 'item-form',                                                                            
    template: `
        <form #exerciseForm="ngForm">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required
           [(ngModel)]="model.title"
           ngControl="title" #name="ngForm" >
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required
           [(ngModel)]="model.time"
           ngControl="number" #name="ngForm" >
        </form>
    `,                                                       
    inputs: ['model:break']                                                                           
})                                                                                                                                                                                                         
export class BreakFormComponent extends ItemFormComponent {                                           
    model = new Break("Title", 10);                                                                            

}
```

**App**

```ts
@Component({
        selector: 'app',
        template: `
          <h1>App</h1>
          <div *ngFor="#item of items">
              <item-form [model]="item"></item-form> <!-- HERE IS WHERE FORM SHOULD BE INSERTED! -->
          </div>
        `,
        directives: [ItemFormComponent]
})
export class App {
    items: Item[] = [new Exercise("Exercise", "Description"), new Break("Break", 10)];
}
```

Comment: TypeScript supports polymorphism, but the Angular annotation doesn't. I think you need to specify the precise name of the class in the directives field, not the abstract superclass.

Comment: Is this "who are children of a parent."  really about parent-child relationship or does this mean superclass-subclass relationship?

Comment: The Angular cookbook's dynamic form recipe has a base Questions class with a `controlType` property that derived class use to indicate control that should be used, and a single question component with a switch statement using `controlType` as the switch variable, and a case for each difference control that the question could use:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html
That might be the best you can do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
      <div *ngFor="#item of items">
          <item-form-a *ngIf="item instanceOf A" [model]="item"></item-form-a>
          <item-form-b *ngIf="item instanceOf B" [model]="item"></item-form-a>
      </div>
```

I don't use TypeScript and don't know if `instanceOf` is supported in Angular expressions. If not you'd need to move the check to a function of `App` and call it like `*ngIf="isInstanceOf(item, A)`.

Comment: I tested with `*ngIf="item instanceof A"` but it isn't supported. I addition I tried with `*ngIf="isInstanceOf(item, A)` but A is always undefined. I don't know why. Hence I created: `*ngIf="isA(item)` but item is intanceof object!?

Comment: That was somehow expected. Types are not member of the component class and bindings don't allow to refer things outside the component. Therefore `A` can't be used in binding expressions at all. I don't know why `isA(item) { return item instanceOf A; }` doesn't work. I don't use TS I just looked the type check up. Maybe you need a workaround so that the items provide a property that allows to check their type (like a string field containing the name of the class).

Comment: @Franb: This actually does not answer your question and should therefore not be marked as such.

Comment: @DioF I think this is entirely up to the one who asked the question if he accepts an answer or not, and which one he accepts.